# Firebase Realtime Database query for two childs in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I don't know if someone deal with something like this before. I have a simple structure in a Firebase Database:

```
channels
  -L5xr3XxRMJ3GOQOyP8t
     name: "test"
     user1: "T00SfCLwbmWbaZJieSb2pSzO7fp1"
     user2: "ylRatW20m6VKnQDXjJdet2GZhgt1"
  -L5xrMGvRGgH6X1mDyP1
     name: "test2"
     user1: "ylRatW20m6VKnQDXjJdet2GZhgt1"
     user2: "T00SfCLwbmWbaZJieSb2pSzO7fp1"
```

In `user1` and `user2` have identifiers for users stored in a different structure. I need to make a query to `channels` sending an user identifiers and checking if that value is in `user1` **OR** `user2`.

I looked for a solution but didn't find anything useful. Anyone can show me the way to follow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no OR type query with Firebase Realtime Database.  You'll have to make two different queries, then merge the results in the app.

Comment: How can you merge two different queries with Swift?

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to do.  You'll have to collect all the results from all the queries into a data structure that meets your needs.

Comment: Ok, what I mean is if there is some kind of function in the Firebase Swift SDK prepare for merging two or more queries, something similar to `Promise.all` in javascript. But it seems there is nothing like that and have to do it manually, right?

Comment: I'm going to guess you have to write code to deal with the contents of the snapshots the way you need.